# Terminal emulator not spawning process

Tags: emacs, elisp, terminal-emulator

`C:/Program Files (x86)/emacs-24.2/bin/cmdproxy.exe` (the one supplied with the copy of Emacs) isn't firing up in the *terminal-emulator*, no matter if I try doing it using `eval` or <kbd>M-x</kbd>. Nor is any other CLI such as `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe` or `D:/user_files/Downloads/plink.exe`.

It returns:

> apply: Spawning child process: invalid argument

when run interactively (<kbd>M-x</kbd>)

or

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Spawning child process" "invalid argument")
  signal(file-error ("Spawning child process" "invalid argument"))
  byte-code("\301 \210\302@A\"\207" [err fundamental-mode signal] 3)
  terminal-emulator("*PUTTY-RUNNING-TAIL*" "D:/user_files/Downloads/plink.exe" ("10.10.0.145"))
  eval((terminal-emulator "*PUTTY-RUNNING-TAIL*" "D:/user_files/Downloads/plink.exe" (cons "192.168.10.8" nil)) nil)
  eval-expression((terminal-emulator "*PUTTY-RUNNING-TAIL*" "D:/user_files/Downloads/plink.exe" (cons "192.168.10.8" nil)) nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
```

when run from `eval` (`(terminal-emulator "*PUTTY-RUNNING-TAIL*" "D:/user_files/Downloads/plink.exe" (cons "192.168.10.8" nil))`).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the root cause of your problem is a hardcoded `/bin/sh` in [`terminal-emulator`](https://github.com/mirrors/emacs/blob/emacs-24.3/lisp/terminal.el) code ([`(start-process "terminal-emulator" (current-buffer) "/bin/sh" "-c" ...`](https://github.com/mirrors/emacs/blob/emacs-24.3/lisp/terminal.el#L1137)).  You could try changing that to a shell that is valid for you, but I am not optimistic about the outcome.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263012/m-x-term-with-emacs-on-ms-windows-error-spawning-child-process-invalid-argum) about a similar problem for a different kind of terminal emulation under Emacs in a Windows based platform.

Comment: Then I suppose it's a bug, in the Windows port of Emacs.